# How do I set up a subdomain with Route53 in EC2 AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I have my main domain (let's call it example.com) pointing to an EC2 instance.

I want to add a staging.example.com subdomain that runs in the same instance, I already created the subdomain in Route53 and point it to the elastic IP using an A record. It is obviously pointing to the root folder and displaying my production site.

How do I redirect it to its own folder and display it as staging.example.com?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to look up [virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) and how to set that up. Which web server are you using?

Route53 seems to be doing what you want it to do. Route53 is pointing both staging.example.com and example.com to the right EC2 instance.

Look at how to setup virtual hosts with apache here - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/

Comment: I am running Apache on a Linux distribution